# How to add customInfo with CXCallUpdate using CallKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, callkit

I want to show both the Name and Phone number in the Recents Log using CallKit. 
I could show the phone number or name using the code below,

```
CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
callUpdate.localizedCallerName = @"Name or Number";
```

Skype displaying both Name and Social Profile label. 
Atleast if possible in the Social Profile label.

**Update**:

I need to add **customInfo**(like unique-id) with the CXCallUpdate, is it possible?

Comment: I am not used to CallKit can you use callUpdate.localizedCallerName = @"Name\nNumber";

Comment: @New16, Nice idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CXHandle` value that you set as the `remoteHandle` of your `CXCallUpdate` will be shown in the page you get when you press the "i" info button in Recents. (It will be shown as either a phone number, an email address, or a "social profile" depending on whether the `CXHandle`'s `type` is phone number, email address, or "generic", respectively.) But it will not show in the actual row in Recents.

Comment: I have another question. I need to pass the custom info while making call, and while call back from recents, I need to read those info. Like how we are doing with UILocalNotification. Can we pass custom info with CXHandle?

Comment: @RJVKumar: I don't think so. The only way is to put it into the handle string itself.

Comment: I don't want to show some parameters to the user about that call. So I asked. I hope in future callkit api will have more updates.